# HiPass Filter - resistors in series?

Tags: high-pass-filter

If i need a 1500 ohm resistor, could I replace with 2 resistors in series, 1000 ohm + 500 ohm without affecting the freq cutoff?

Comment: How is this unclear? This question is legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly you can unless of course the cut-off frequency is higher than a few hundred MHz.

Comment: thanks  Andy, the cut off freq is 30 hertz for a electric bass.  I figured as much but always good to ask silly questions.

Comment: I don't think those values will suit an electric bass (conventional pups) because the output impedance is so high and the 1500 ohms (in the pass band) will ruin the signal level. You realistically need to be thinking a minimum of many tens of kohm i.e. make the resistor ten times bigger and the capacitor ten times smaller. If not a hundred times bigger for R and a hundred times smaller for C.